# random forest package of R - curious behavior of node size parameter

Tags: r, random-forest

I have used the random forest package of R for supervised classification with no stopping criteria defined by the user. Well, the default of the node size is one, but many end nodes contain more than one sample. What make the algorithm stops while the node size is not still one? I have set `mtry`, the number of variables sampled at each split, with training the RF.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: If you read the doc, it says "*minimum* size of terminal nodes." So it doesn't have to end up with just one observation for every terminal node.

Answer (score 9):

Nodes are split until purity or until the minimum node size is reached, whichever comes first.

(This is a short answer, but it's literally all there is to say on this topic.)